# How can i show all edges in monogame?

Tags: c#, 3d, xna-4.0, monogame

I am using `Monogame 3.5` and i have simple model of cube. I use `BasicEffect` to draw it. I want it transparent so i use `effect.Alpha = 0.5f`. Is it possible to show all edges something like on picture?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could change the RasterizerState fill mode.

```
RasterizerState rasterizerState = new RasterizerState();
rasterizerState.FillMode = FillMode.WireFrame;
GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = rasterizerState;
```